# calculated return from entityrepository method

Tags: doctrine, symfony

Was wondering if its possible (or maybe just not best practice) to return a calculated value from an EntityRepository method, or if I should be doing the calculation somewhere else. For example.

My Entity Users have Times (times are a Day of the week and a corresponding time for that day of the week not a hard date)

Looking to write a function that returns their NEXT time specific to the date, so for example if today is 2/8/16 (Monday) and the next "Time" is `Tuesday at 12:00PM` I want the function to simply return a DateTime object reflecting `2/9/16 12:00PM`

Comment: It's certainly possible.  You want to avoid having too many unrelated functions in a given class.  But if you only have a few and they are all directly related to Users then sneaking them into the repository is okay.  Saves you from having to manage an additional service.  If other classes besides users need this sort of functionality then make an independent date service.

Comment: @cerad Could I put a function like this directly in my Entity Class or is it better to be in the EntityRepository. Pros/Cons??... Essentially every instance would have a calculable date or NULL if none exists in the case the user didn't have an "Times" defined, then there could never be a "next" date.  Or is it better to just keep the entity with Getters and Setters and that's it and work other custom functions into the repositor or like you suggest making a service...

Comment: If your function only applies to users and does not need to access the database then you can put it in your entity class.  It's called business logic.  Just make sure it's all related to users.  If you start needing to create fake uses just to get access to the function then you should move it elsewhere.

Comment: Ok thanks I think you've pointed me in the right direction. I can figure out the code I need to write, I sometimes am questionable on WHERE to place that code when using symfony. Sometimes I find it easier to get the information in one place or another but not sure if its acceptable to place that function there. For example is easier to say `$this->getTimes()` and do the work and return a datetime rather than trying to do the same thing in the repository passing the user object in and have to write DQL.